# onClick is getting called in the rendering itself of image tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a series of image tags, which have `onClick` on them. In the `onClick`, I am calling a function called camera, with parameters 
for imagetag1, 2 for imagetag2 and 3 for imagetag3
In the camera, I am checking the parameter and doing setState. **But while rendering itself onClick is getting called!** I don't understand this phenomena. `Is there is any other way that I should send the id to onClick function`?.
 Here is my code

```
camera: function(id){

  console.log(id);
    var that = this;
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
      });

      function onSuccess(imageData) {

          var finalimage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

          var temp;
          if(that.id === 1){
            temp ="image1";
          }else if(that.id ===2){
            temp = "image2";
          }else if(that.id === 3){
             temp = "image3"; 
          }

          that.setState({temp:finalimage});

      }


     function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
     }


 },

render: function(){
return(
      <div>
      <img  className="addpicture" onClick={this.camera(1)} src={this.state.image1} />
      <img  className="addpicture" onClick={this.camera(2)} src={this.state.image2} />
      <img  className="addpicture" onClick={this.camera(3)} src={this.state.image3} />
      </div>
      ); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is odd but your doing it quite right, the only thing is that you must use other attribute, instead of calling your function, here's how

```
camera: function(event){
    var id = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-cam'));
    console.log(id);
    // other code 
}
render: function(){
return(
  <div>
  <img className="addpicture" onClick={this.camera} src={this.state.image1} data-cam={1} />
  <img className="addpicture" onClick={this.camera} src={this.state.image2} data-cam={2} />
  <img className="addpicture" onClick={this.camera} src={this.state.image3} data-cam={3} />
  </div>
  ); 
}
```

click event or any other events passes event object as argument to your custom event handler function, so you just need to detect that Dom element and get desired attribute

Comment: how do I get the camera id?

Comment: @gates basically click event passes arguments to your camera function, so you just need to detect that Dom element and get desired attribute

Comment: Lemme check, I see you are constantly making edits ;)

Comment: @gates I love full coverage of answer

Comment: Check other variants, Use console.log(event.target) to see exactly which element is clicked, and if it has that cameraid attribute. Basically this solution answers this question, you just need more experience in JavaScript itself, as getting Dom element and retrieving its attributes doesn't have anything with reactjs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85285/discussion-between-gates-and-evc).

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the currentTarget from the click event.

```
camera: function(event){
  event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-cam')
}

<img className="addpicture" onClick={this.camera} src={this.state.image1} data-cam={1} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought the other answer is accepted, I would right how I solved this issue when I was getting it.
I had to use `bind`, don't know why yet.

So use it this way:

`<img  className="addpicture" onClick={this.camera.bind(this, 1)} src={this.state.image1} />`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this without binding an event handler.

Evaluated during render():

```
<img src={image} onClick={func()} />
```

Evaluated on click:

```
<img src={image} onClick={(e) => func()} />
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that `onClick` here gets assigned a value of what the whole `{this.camera(1)}` evaluates to. Hence the calling of this function.

I don't see how you could assign those events by the event attribute *and* using `this`.

What you should do is generate the template just as you are doing right now, but assign the events afterwards (or in an temporary DOM node) with regular `addEventListener` function.

In doing so, the handler (camera funcion) may still remain a private function, when assigned to event from within the object.

Comment: So you mean to say this is an issue with the react?

Comment: Oh, ok. I think you could have mentioned the react is involved ;) Not in the tag only. In this light, the answer is inappropriate.